# Pandas join.fillna of two data frames replaces all all values with anf not only nan

Tags: python, pandas, join, nan

The following code will update the number of items in stock based on the index. The table dr with the old stock holds >1000 values. The updated data frame grp1 contains the number of sold items. I would like to subtract data frame grp1 from data frame dr and update dr. Everything is fine until I want to join grp1 to dr with Panda's join and fillna. First of all datatypes are changed from int to float and not only the NaN but also the notnull values are replaced by 0. Is this a problem with not matching indices?

I tried to make the dtypes uniform but this has not changed anything. Removing fillna while joining the two dataframes returns NaN for all columns.

```py
dr has the following format (example):

druck_pseudonym   lager_nr  menge_im_lager
80009359            62808               1
80009360            62809              10
80009095            62810               0
80009364            62811              11
80009365            62812              10
80008572            62814              10
80009072            62816              18
80009064            62817              13
80009061            62818               2
80008725            62819               3
80008940            62820              12


dr.dtypes
lager_nr          int64
menge_im_lager    int64
dtype: object

and grp1 (example):
LagerArtikelNummer1         ArtMengen1
880211066                      1
80211070                      1
80211072                      2
80211073                      2
80211082                      2
80211087                      4
80211091                      1
80211107                      2
88889272                      1
88889396                      1


ArtMengen1    int64
dtype: object

#update list with "nicht_erledigt"
dr_update = dr.join(grp1).fillna(0)
dr_update["menge_im_lager"] = dr_update["menge_im_lager"] - dr_update["ArtMengen1"]
```

This returns:

```py
                lager_nr  menge_im_lager  ArtMengen1
druck_pseudonym                                      
80009185            44402            26.0         0.0
80009184            44403             2.0         0.0
80009182            44405            16.0         0.0
80008894            44406            32.0         0.0
80008115            44407             3.0         0.0
80008974            44409            16.0         0.0
80008380            44411             4.0         0.0

dr_update.dtypes
lager_nr            int64
menge_im_lager    float64
ArtMengen1        float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Editing after comment, indices are object.

Your indices are string objects. You need to convert these to numeric. Use

```
dr.index = pd.to_numeric(dr.index) 
grp1.index = pd.to_numeric(grp1.index)

dr.sort_index()
grp1.sort_index()
```

Then try the rest...

You can filter the old stock 'dr' dataframe to match the sold stock, then substract, and assing back to the original filtered dataframe.

```
# Filter the old stock dataframe so that you have matching index to the sold dataframe. 
# Restrict just for menge_im_lager. Then subtract the sold stock
dr.loc[dr.index.isin(grp1.index), "menge_im_lager"] = (
    dr.loc[dr.index.isin(grp1.index), "menge_im_lager"] - grp1["ArtMengen1"]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces just a series of nan and a run time warning ase.py:3772: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar before with astype(int), which did not work on the index. So I reseted the Index and then converted it to integer. However, your solution is defenitely the elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, firstly you want the non-matching indices to be in your final dataset and you want your final dataset to be integers. You can use 'outer' join and astype int for your dataset. 
So, at the join you can do it this way:

```
dr.join(grp1,how='outer').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: This produces just a dataframe of nan.